# Restart other application. C#, .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I want to restart some process. Lets call it someApp.exe.
How can I restart that process? It's not my application. It's some external program.

Comment: How would you do that manually, without C#?

Comment: @ Oscar Mederos - In task menager -> Kill process -> Start Process

Comment: After you Kill it, how can you start it again? I mean, where do you see the process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do is:

- Kill the process
- Start it again

There are some ways of obtaining a Process instance in C#. Let's suppose you know the name of the process:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad++")[0];
```

Then you can do:

```
process.Kill();
```

But to start it again, you need to know the path of the process, so before killing it, save the path of the executable:

```
var path = process.MainModule.FileName;
```

And then you can do:

```
Process.Start(path);
```

---

**You should** check if `GetProcessesByName` returns elements before taking the first element, but I just wanted to focus on the important thing here.

Comment: what about program start arguments ? (like what we see in taskmanager for command line collumn)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Process.Start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx#Y1400