# AUTOMATIC restarting of Program If program crashes in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying this in c# but I can't find a solution for that please help
What I want is an AUTOMATIC restarting of Program "B" IF Program "A" is not running anymore.

here is the code that i have tried

```
public void ReLaunch()
        {
            try
            {

                Process DKU = new Process();
                DKU.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe";
                DKU.Start();
                DKU.WaitForExit(10 * 60 * 1000);

                if (!DKU.HasExited)
                {
                    DKU.Kill();
                    Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\Steam\steamapps\common\Neverwinter Nights\bin\win32\nwserver.exe";
                    process.Start();


                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Please give right path");
            }

        }
```

I don't know how to do that in c# please help me thanks

Comment: Can you edit the code of both program A and program B?

Comment: why not use try catch and handling it?

Comment: refer to this answer  which describes how to start new process  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954033/restart-other-application-c-net

Comment: Help me, please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read these pages: "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". It's not useful to repeated ask us to help you, it won't get help any faster. Instead make sure you wrote a well-asked question and then we can help you more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not having a big picture of what you are trying to accomplish and how this should be deployed and run.

I am not saying that my solution is the most efficient way to do the things, but I just wanted to give you some insight into ideas on how you can do it, so you get your own ideas.

Please take a look at my code, if you have questions, feel free to ask. If you like my example and it helped you mark it as the right answer and like it.

NOTE: To run the code, create a new .Net Framework console project, copy and paste my code to Program.cs. Ensure that you have NotePad++ installed or use another program that you like. Run the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var notepadPlusPlus = new Process();
            notepadPlusPlus.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";
            notepadPlusPlus.Start(); 

            var processWatcher = new ProcessWatcher(Execute, notepadPlusPlus.ProcessName, 2000);
            processWatcher.StartWatch();

            Console.WriteLine("To exit press any key. Currently awiating Noptepad++.exe. to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Notepad++.exe has been closed. Starting Notepad.exe");

            var notepad = new Process();
            notepad.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
            notepad.Start(); 
        }
   }

   public class ProcessWatcher
   {
       private readonly string _processName;
       private readonly Action _callbackMethod;
       private Timer _scanTimer;

       public ProcessWatcher(Action callbackMethod, string processName, int scanInterval)
       {
            _processName = processName;
            _callbackMethod = callbackMethod;

           _scanTimer = new Timer(scanInterval);
           _scanTimer.Elapsed += _scanTimer_Elapsed;
       }

       public void StartWatch()
       {
            _scanTimer.Start();
            _scanTimer.AutoReset = true;
       }

       public void StopWatch()
       {
           _scanTimer.Stop();
       }

       private void _scanTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
       {
            var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(_processName);
            if (!processes.Any())
            {
                _callbackMethod.Invoke();
                StopWatch();
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr:DasSoftware i really appreciate that, it worked happily but I need one more help could you please change this to windows form, please

Comment: Yes, of course! can you give me a bit more info about your app? A bit more code would be good and I will try to help!

Comment: actually your code is working fine so please I want you to convert your above into windows form in c#. then my work would be clear thanks, and please help me

Comment: I prepared a demo, that you can use and expand to your needs. You can find it here: https://github.com/MeatDuckXp/ApplicationWatch

Happy coding and good luck!

Comment: Please don't use salutations ("Hi"), valedictions ("Hope this helps") or signatures ("Fred") on SO. The site isn't a message board, instead every question and associated answers are an article in an online reference book. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/153968 will help.